# Solve an easy task please, can't make all Test Cases right

Tags: python-3.x

**Problem Description:**
John is travelling by train, The fare of the train depends on the kilometer he traveled. For the first A kilometer, the fare is M and for the subsequent distance, it is N per kilometer. You are given total distance covered by train. Find out the total fare.

**Input:**
Each input contains four space separated Integer A,M,N,D(total distance).

**Output:**
Print the value of total fare.

**Constraints:**
1<=A,M,N,D<=1000

**Sample Input:**
1 2 3 5

**Sample Output:**
14

My code(doesn't work):

```
a, m, n, d = input().split()
s = 0
if int(a) > int(d):
    s += int(m)
else:
    s += int(a)*int(m)
for i in range(int(a), int(d)):
    s += int(n)
print(s)
```

Comment: Isn't it just `m + n * (d - a)`?

Comment: no it is a bit more

Comment: Alright, `m + n * (d-a) if d > a else m`, then, at least the way I interpret the A >= D case.

Comment: sry I mean that if `d>a` the it will be `m*d` not `m`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a, m, n, d = input().split()
s = 0
if int(a) > int(d):
    s += int(m)*int(d)
else:
    s += int(a)*int(m)
    s += (int(d) - int(a))* int(n)
print(s)
```

This should work well

Comment: happy to help !